# Testing akka tells without using Thread.sleep

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

i'm trying to develop a simple unit test to bind a port on my machine, test that the port is bound, then release the port and test that it is release. Currently I'm using this naive approach

```
class ServerTest extends FlatSpec with MustMatchers {
  "Server" must "bind a tcp server to an address on our machine" in {
    //if this fails this means that the port is in use before our test case is run
    val port = 18333
    isBound(port) must be (false)
    val actor = Server()
    actor ! Tcp.Bind(actor, new InetSocketAddress(port))
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    isBound(port) must be (true)
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    actor ! Tcp.Unbind
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    isBound(port) must be (false)
  }


  /**
    * Tests if a specific port number is bound on our machine
    * @param port
    * @return
    */
  def isBound(port : Int) : Boolean = {
    val tryBinding : Try[Unit] = Try {
      val socket = new java.net.Socket()
      socket.connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(port),1000)
      socket.close()
    }

    tryBinding.isSuccess
  }
}
```

I would like to test this without using the calls to `Thread.sleep` since this is a blocking call. Can anyone provide me with a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending `TCP.Bind` , you should expect a reply stating either success or failure: http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.2/akka/io/Tcp.Bind.html

> The Bind message is send to the TCP manager actor, which is obtained
>   via TcpExt.manager() in order to bind to a listening socket. The
>   manager replies either with a Tcp.CommandFailed or the actor handling
>   the listen socket replies with a Tcp.Bound message. If the local port
>   is set to 0 in the Bind message, then the Tcp.Bound message should be
>   inspected to find the actual port which was bound to.

You should use AkkaTestKit (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html) and use either `ImplicitSender` or a `TestProbe` to send the `TCP.Bind`, and then wait for the answer.

For example:

```
val probe = TestProbe()
probe.send(actor, Tcp.Bind(actor, new InetSocketAddress(port)))
probe.expectMsg(Tcp.Bound)
```

Your test code will either continue when the reply is received, or fail if not received within the timeout (which is configurable in the `expectMsg` call).

Comment: I've tried to follow your test case on another actor I have here and for some reason the TestProbe is missing the message, could you look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706268/testprobe-missing-akka-message

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
within (1000 millisends) {
...
}
```

see https://github.com/RayRoestenburg/AkkaExamples/blob/master/src/test/scala/unit/akka/TestKitUsageSpec.scala for more examples

Comment: I'm familiar with `within` however, I'm not familiar with how to use `within` to determine the that ordering of of those events is tested correctly.